# Is it possible to compare XML and JSON code for equality?

Tags: javascript, json, xml, rest

**XML response is like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ReturnCode>525</ReturnCode>
  <ReturnMessage>Coupon maximum usage limit reached.</ReturnMessage> 
</Response>
```

**JSON response is like this:**

```
{"Response":{"@xmlns:xsi":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", 
             "@xmlns:xsd":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
             "ReturnCode":"429",
             "ReturnMessage":"Invalid Coupon offer code"}}
```

**Question:** How can I compare and determine whether these two are same without converting?

Answer (score 4):

XML and JSON are mere data formats.  Comparison implies a basis, typically a semantic one, so the *general* answer to your question is **no, you cannot tell whether two arbitrary XML and JSON messages mean the same.**

In any particular case, however, one might assume that similarly named data ought to have the same values.   In your case, your XML sample has data `ReturnCode` with a value of 525, yet your JSON has data `ReturnCode` of 429.  Therefore, it'd be reasonable to *assume* that **your XML and your JSON are *not* the same.**